# How to select efficiently from a long list of options in react-select

Tags: react-select

My use case is to allow the user to select a ticker from a long list of about 8000 companies. I fetch all the companies when the component mounts, so I don't really need the async feature of react-select. The problem really is displaying and scrolling through the 8000 items (as described in several open issues like [this one](https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/2850)).

My thought is why display 8000 entries when the user can't do anything meaningful with such a big list anyway. Instead why not show a maximum of 5 matches. As the user types more, the matches keep getting better. Specifically:

- When the input is blank, show no options
- When the input is a single character, there will still be hundreds of matches, but show only the first 5
- As the user keeps on typing, the number of matches will reduce, but still limited to 5. However they will be more relavant.

I am not seeing this solution mentioned anywhere, so was wondering if it makes sense. Also wanted to find out what's the best way to implement it with react-select. I have tried the following two approaches - can you think of a better way:

**Approach 1: Use Async React Select**

Although I don't need async fetching, I can use this feature to filter down the options. It seems to work very well:

```
const filterCompanies = (value: string) => {
    const inputValue = value.trim().toLowerCase();
    const inputLength = inputValue.length;
    let count = 0;

    return inputLength === 0
        ? []
        : companies.filter(company => {
              const keep =
                  count < 5 &&
                  (company.ticker.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) >= 0 ||
                      company.name.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputValue) >= 0);

              if (keep) {
                  count += 1;
              }

              return keep;
          });
};

const promiseOptions = (inputValue: string) =>
    Promise.resolve(filterCompanies(inputValue));

return (
    <AsyncSelect<Company>
        loadOptions={promiseOptions}
        value={selectedCompany}
        getOptionLabel={option => `${option.ticker} - ${option.name}`}
        getOptionValue={option => option.ticker}
        isClearable={true}
        isSearchable={true}
        onChange={handleChange}
    />
);
```

**Approach 2: Use filterOption**

Here I am using the `filterOption` to directly filter down the list. However it does not work very well - the filterOption function is very myopic - it gets only one candidate option at a time and needs to decide if that matches or not. Using this approach I cannot tell whether I have crossed the limit of showing 5 options or not. Net result: with blank input I am showing all 8000 options, as user starts typing, the number of options is reduced but still pretty large - so the sluggishness is still there. I would have thought that `filterOption` would be the more direct approach for my use case but it turns out that it is not as good as the async approach. Am I missing something?

```
const filterOption = (candidate: Option, input: string) => {
    const { ticker, name } = candidate.data;
    const inputVal = input.toLowerCase();

    return (
        ticker.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputVal) >= 0 ||
        name.toLowerCase().indexOf(inputVal) >= 0
    );
};

return (
    <ReactSelect
        options={companies}
        value={selectedCompany}
        filterOption={filterOption}
        getOptionLabel={option => `${option.ticker} - ${option.name}`}
        getOptionValue={option => option.ticker}
        isClearable={true}
        isSearchable={true}
        onChange={handleChange}
    />

);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can try using react-window to replace the menulist component

ref : https://github.com/JedWatson/react-select/issues/3128#issuecomment-431397942